# How to use a .catch in firebase onSnapshot

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I've created an Ionic Firebase chat app.  The problem I think I'm having is I've set up a query snapshot on initialization of the message page with the following:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
      this.messageService.getAllMessages()
      .doc(`${this.userId[0] + '-' + this.userId[1]}`)
      .collection('message')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        this.messages = [];
        doc.forEach((snap) => {
          this.messages.push({
            content: snap.data().content,
            createdAt: snap.data().createdAt,
            userId: snap.data().userId
          });
        });
        console.log('messages', this.messages);
      });
  }
```

The problem is if there are no messages on the initial attempt to send a message the page doesn't load the first time I attempt to go to it.

The message is a little obscure but I'm pretty sure I'm having this issue because Firebase isn't returning any data but there's no way to add a .catch in the query to catch the error and handle it so that the user can still navigate to the message page.

```js
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
    at _throwError (vendor.js:70776)
    at setUpControl (vendor.js:70646)
    at NgModel._setUpStandalone (vendor.js:73693)
    at NgModel._setUpControl (vendor.js:73668)
    at NgModel.ngOnChanges (vendor.js:73604)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.js:63813)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js:65493)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:65432)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:66400)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.js:66343)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3193)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3150)
    at polyfills.js:3254
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2785)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:57358)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2784)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2557)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2963)
defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:55398
handleError @ vendor.js:55450
next @ vendor.js:57952
schedulerFn @ vendor.js:52576
__tryOrUnsub @ vendor.js:133918
next @ vendor.js:133857
_next @ vendor.js:133804
next @ vendor.js:133781
next @ vendor.js:133566
emit @ vendor.js:52556
(anonymous) @ vendor.js:57389
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ polyfills.js:2753
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ polyfills.js:2512
runOutsideAngular @ vendor.js:57315
onHandleError @ vendor.js:57389
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ polyfills.js:2757
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ polyfills.js:2526
_loop_1 @ polyfills.js:3056
api.microtaskDrainDone @ polyfills.js:3065
drainMicroTaskQueue @ polyfills.js:2970
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.js:2946
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:2775
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.js:2663
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:2766
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:2600
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.js:2620
scheduleResolveOrReject @ polyfills.js:3241
resolvePromise @ polyfills.js:3187
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3103
webpackJsonpCallback @ runtime.js:26
(anonymous) @ pages-messages-messages-module.js:1
vendor.js:116244 POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channe
```

So my question is, is there a way to handle null return values in the .Snapshot query in firebase?

I've tried this:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    try {
      this.messageService.getAllMessages()
      .doc(`${this.users[0] + '-' + this.users[1]}`)
      .collection('message')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        this.messages = [];
        doc.forEach((snap) => {
          this.messages.push({
            content: snap.data().content,
            createdAt: snap.data().createdAt,
            userId: snap.data().userId
          });
        });
        console.log('messages', this.messages);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Message page error', error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Going back to your original question: 'How do you handle an error onSnapshot' - is there a way? I don't believe you can chain a catch to it, and I'm stumped because it doesn't tell you which 'onSnapshot' had the error either and it makes things difficult to debug without a stack trace.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While [Doug answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199024/1377145) is correct, you **still need** to catch error for `onSnapshot` when **permission is denied**

For that, use the following syntax:

```js
const unsubscribeMe = firestoreInstance
    .collection('example')
    .onSnapshot(
        querySnapshot => {
            if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                return
            }
            const organizations = querySnapshot.docs.map(ref => ({
                id: ref.id,
                ...ref.data(),
            }))
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error)
        }
    )
```

See the [javascript reference here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#onsnapshot) which contain additional method signature that may fit your need.

Answer (score 3):

A Firestore query doesn't fail if it finds no matching documents. It simply provides a QuerySnapshot that contains no documents.

The `doc` variable in your code is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) type object (so, it's not a "document").  It has a method called [empty()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty) that you can use to see if it contains no documents.  Alternately, you can check its [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property for zero length.

```js
.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  if (!querySnapshot.empty()) {
    this.messages = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      this.messages.push({
        content: snap.data().content,
        createdAt: snap.data().createdAt,
        userId: snap.data().userId
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    // what do you want to do if there are no documents?
  }
});
```

Based on the suggestions I've updated my code with the following and having the same issue:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.messageService.getAllMessages()
    .doc(`${this.users[0] + '-' + this.users[1]}`)
    .collection('message')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
      if (!doc.empty) {
        this.messages = [];
        doc.forEach((snap) => {
          this.messages.push({
            content: snap.data().content,
            createdAt: snap.data().createdAt,
            userId: snap.data().userId
          });
        });
      } else {
        this.messages = [];
      }

      console.log('messages', this.messages);
    });
}
```

```html
<ion-list lines="none" *ngIf="messages.length > 0">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages; index as i; trackBy: trackByCreated">
    <div size="9" *ngIf="theirItinerary.userId === msg.userId" class="message other-user">
      <span>{{msg.content}}</span>
      <div class="time" text-right><br> {{msg.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
    </div>
    <div offset="3" size="9" *ngIf="theirItinerary.userId !== msg.userId" class="message me" slot="end">
      <span>{{msg.content}}</span>
      <div class="time" text-right><br> {{msg.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar light="light">
    <ion-row align-items-center no-padding>
      <ion-col size="8">
        <textarea autosize maxRows="3" [(ngModel)]="newMsg" class="message-input"></textarea>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="3">
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" color="primary" [disabled]="newMsg === ''" class="msg-btn" (click)="sendMessage()">
          <ion-icon name="ios-send" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Thanks Doug.  Your snippet helped me determine that the query wasn't causing the problem and it's something else.  I've added the html I'm using and my updated code based on your suggestions.  Can you see anything else that may be causing this problem?

Comment: Try doing a web search on the error message.  "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
"

Comment: I figured it out...the html had labels dependent on the data from firebase.  I added an ngIf for the properties and resolved the issue.