# How to Programmatically know if firestore couldn't fetch data when offline

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps

I am making a chat application with firebase as my backend. I render out all the Room names by an `useEffect` like this :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  db.collection('chats')
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
      setChats(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        })),
      ),
    );
}, []);
```

I am converting it into a PWA but the problem is when **my app is offline it does not render the Room names and gives an error that**

> you do not have a healthy connection

How do I know when this happens because what I thought is that when my app is offline it should fetch all the Room names from the local storage, so **I need to know when `firestore` is not able to fetch the data**

Comment: how about adding catch error something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198904/how-to-use-a-catch-in-firebase-onsnapshot

Comment: I will try and update here thanks for responding